# React Router changes URL but does not render the new component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm new to React Router.

The URL renders in the address bar when I click the Links but the content doesn't render. This is using React-Router version 4. When I click on the Link in the Navigation Bar, I want to be able to visit the links listed such as Home page, or the Blogpost page.

**Navbar Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Blogpost from "./Blogpost";


export default class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div id="header">
            <Link to='/app'>App</Link>
            <Link to='/'>Blogpost</Link>

        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

**Home Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { database } from "../firebase";
import _ from "lodash";
import renderHTML from "react-render-html";
import "../App.css";
import App from "./App";
import Header from "./Header";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Blogpost from "./Blogpost";

export default class Home extends Component {

....

render() {
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Blogpost} />
      </Switch>
      <Header />
      <br />
      <div className="homeData">{this.renderPosts()}</div>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
 }
}
```

**Index.js Component**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Blogpost from "./components/Blogpost";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(<Blogpost />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: In your console, there might be an error. To say the least, I am **guessing** that  `<Link to='/app'>` would be apprehending the link to URL but It does not know *what* to render since it isn't getting props. I don't use react-router this way so can't say wether this is right or wrong. Alternatively, Can you create sandbox version?

Comment: there is no route declared for `'/app'`